# Ruby class properties

Tags: ruby, class

The quiz problem:

> Which of the following statements about classes in Ruby are true?
>
> 1. `Array` is an instance of `Class`.
> 2. When `self` is used within the definition of an instance method, it refers to the current instance of the class.
> 3. Ruby supports multiple inheritance.
> 4. Public methods of a class cannot be redefined after an instance of that class is instantiated.

More than one answer could be correct.

I know that (3) is incorrect because Ruby does not support multiple inheritance. I chose (1) but got the question wrong. Are other statements about the classes in Ruby also true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR

#1 and #2 are both correct answers. You already know that Ruby doesn't support multiple inheritance, although it *does* support module mixins. So, 3 and 4 are false, while 1 and 2 are true; see below for details.

### Array.is_a? Class

First of all, Array *is* a class, but doesn't inherit from Class or have Class in its ancestry. Consider:

```
Array.is_a? Class
# => true

Array.ancestors
# => [Array, Enumerable, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]

Array < Class
# => nil
```

On the other hand, as @Priti correctly points out in his comment below, Array is an *instance* of Class:

```
Array.instance_of? Class
# => true
```

So, while Array doesn't inherit from Class in its ancestry chain, it is (strictly speaking) an instance of a Class. That makes #1 technically correct.

### Object#self

The [self](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-self) method is actually a bit more complex than one might expect. Ruby 1.9 defines it this way:

> self is the "current object" and the default receiver of messages (method calls) for which no explicit receiver is specified. Which object plays the role of self depends on the context.
>
> - In a method, the object on which the method was called is self
> - In a class or module definition (but outside of any method definition contained therein), self is the class or module object being defined.
> - In a code block associated with a call to class_eval (aka module_eval), self is the class (or module) on which the method was called.
> - In a block associated with a call to instance_eval or instance_exec, self is the object on which the method was called.

So, #2 is correct, but only tells part of the story.

### Open Classes

Ruby supports open classes (see [Classes are Open](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/)), so you can redefine instance and class methods at run-time. So, #4 is wrong.

Comment: *Array is an instance of Class.* I think it is *true*. `Array.instance_of? Class # => true`.

Comment: Classes never have `Class` as an ancestor. `class Foo; end; Foo.ancestors => [Foo, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`. `Array.class => Class`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald: `Class.ancestors # => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Comment: Okay, non-anonymous classes don't have Class as an ancestor. Classes have themselves as ancestors, which is why Class has itself as an ancestor.

Comment: To expound, `#ancestors` starts at self and iterates until `#superclass` returns nil, testing each value to see if it is a class. Since classes are somewhat special in that their name is defined by the constant they are assigned to, when iterating a class's ancestors, the class itself appears in the ancestors list, rather than the Class class, except in the case of anonymous classes, which are not assigned to any constant.

Comment: I'd never seen the accepted answer to be the only one with negative vote counts, nice! ;)

Answer (score 3):

While all other answers are explaining each options,but I think *Array is an instance of Class.* is *true*.[Object#instance_of?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_of-3F) says: **Returns true if obj is an instance of the given class. See also Object#kind_of?.**

```
   Array.instance_of? Class # => true
```

Answer (score 1):

2 is also correct.  Self works like this in many languages.
http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html

Answer (score 0):

1, 2, and 3 are true. `Array` is an instance of `Class`, `self` is always the receiver, and Ruby does support multiple mixin inheritance. 4 is false, methods can be added, removed, and modified at any point in time.

Comment: I would argue that 3 is false; mixins are not inheritance. Ruby classes cannot descend from multiple ancestors for any given generation. Mixins are what we use instead of multiple inheritance, but they are not multiple inheritance in the C++ or Python sense.